# Rails ruby-mechanize how to get a page after redirection

Tags: ruby, web-scraping, mechanize-ruby

I want to collect manufacturers and their medicine details from http://www.mims.com/India/Browse/Alphabet/All?cat=Company&tab=company.

**Mechanize** gem is used to extract content from html page with help of ryan [Tutorial](http://railscasts.com/episodes/191-mechanize)

I can login successfully but couldn't reach desination page http://www.mims.com/India/Browse/Alphabet/All?cat=Company&tab=company.

I have tried so far

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'nokogiri'
require 'open-uri'
require 'mechanize'
agent = Mechanize.new
agent.user_agent = 'Individueller User-Agent'
agent.user_agent_alias = 'Linux Mozilla'

agent.get("https://sso.mims.com/Account/SignIn") do |page|
  #login_page = a.click(page.link_with(:text => /Login/))
  # Submit the login form
  login_page = page.form_with(:action => '/') do |f|
    f.SignInEmailAddress = 'username of mims'
    f.SignInPassword = 'secret'
  end.click_button

  url = 'http://www.mims.com/India/Browse/Alphabet/A?cat=drug'
  page = agent.get url # here checking authentication if success then redirecting to destination
  p page
end
```

Note: I have shared dummy login credential for your testing

After clicks on 'CompaniesBrowse Company Directory' link, page redirecting with flash message "you are redirecting...", Mechanize gem caches this page.

Question:

1) How to get the original page(after redirection).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found problem cases that MIMS site auto submit form with page onload callback for checking authentication. It is not working with machanize gem.

**Solution**
Manually submitting the form two times solves this issue. Example

```
url = 'http://www.mims.com/India/Browse/Alphabet/A?cat=drug'
page = agent.get url # here checking authentication if success then redirecting to destination
p page
page.form.submit
agent.page.form.submit
```